# How to turn off dragable behaviour on Google Maps V2 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to set up a Google Maps on device and on top of it show some simple buttons. But events that I attach to those buttons seems to interferee somehow with map drag functionaliy. Basically drag completly doesnt work and also gives me this button not workin. I really dont care about this drag (I dont need it) - but i cant figure out how to disable it.

Does any of you tried that? (I dont want to use static google images only, I still want to have an option to move around, zoom in and out, but on my own buttons). Biggest problem is markers - because I want to have them be clickable. So There might be 2 solutions:

1. How to disable dragable behaviour?
2. How to make only markers clickable (outside of a Map layer somehow, but able to move together with map).

I was thinking in hacky way to create an overlay that would pass only few events but this doesnt work... Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try `map.disableDragging()`? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2

Comment: No I did not found that LOL its in an API... OMG make an answer for that and I will accept :)

Comment: I tested and it works as planned so again - create answer and I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent map from scrolling you must setScrollGesturesEnabled to false on UiSettings:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```